# What is wrong with this void pointer to struct cast?

Tags: c++, c

The task here is to call out everything that is wrong with this snippet. I do not know if the code is being presented as C or C++, so either assumption is valid and helpful.

```
struct MyStructData
{
    VOID* pPtr;
    UINT32 flags;
}

VOID main()
{
    MyStructData* pMyStructData = InitFunction();
    // work done here
    DeInitFunction(pMyStructData);
}

MyStructData* InitFunction()
{
    MyStructData* pMyStructData = malloc(sizeof(MyStructData));
    pMyStructData->pPtr         = malloc(1024);

    return pMyStructData;
}

VOID DeInitFunction(MyStructData* pMyStructData)
{
    free(pMyStructData);
}
```

I see the void pointer is declared, then in `InitFunction`, `pMyStructData` has malloc with size of the struct `MyStructData`. Next the `pPtr` member is accessed and malloc-ed a big chunk (1024)... this is where I see an issue. Since the `pPtr` member was declared as void, `pMyStructData` is too small to allocate 1024 bytes?

Please help me to understand what is happening here, and what I missed.

Comment: Please post the code as text in the question body rather than an image

Comment: You don't `free(pMyStructData->pPtr);`.

Comment: There is no data type `VOID` or `UINT323` in C. Also `MyStructData` does not exist unless you use C++. All required headers are missing.

Comment: Also: there is a semicolon missing after the definion of MyStructData.

Comment: Is that homework to spot errors or is there some other problem hidden behind?

Comment: `main` should return an `int`.

Comment: Not a hw problem, but I just need to outline everything wrong with the snippet. The problem doesn't say if the code is in .c or .cpp ... you make some valid points that made me realize the code is likely being presented as C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was provided before language tag was changed from C to C++.

```c
struct MyStructData
{
    VOID* pPtr;
    UINT32 flags;
}
```

There are no types `VOID` or `UINT32` in C unless you include some headers providing them. Maybe some Windows stuff?

Also a `;` is missing after that struct declaration. (Thanks to wildplasser)

```c
VOID main()
```

Valid signatures for `main` are `int main(void)` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` or compatible.

```c
{
    MyStructData* pMyStructData = InitFunction();
```

There is no type `MyStructData`. Use `struct MyStructData` or add a `typedef`.

You do not provide a prototype for `InitFunction()`.

```c
    // work done here
    DeInitFunction(pMyStructData);
}
```

Same here: No prototype for `DeInitFunction`

```c
MyStructData* InitFunction()
{
    MyStructData* pMyStructData = malloc(sizeof(MyStructData));
```

Again: Use `struct MyStructData`.

Use of `malloc` without prototype. Include proper headers.

```c
    pMyStructData->pPtr         = malloc(1024);
```

Basically valid (except for missing prototype), but you should check if `pMyStructData` is `NULL` before dereferencing it.

```c
    return pMyStructData;
}

VOID DeInitFunction(MyStructData* pMyStructData)
{
    free(pMyStructData);
}
```

As Johnny Mopp mentioned, `pMyStructData->pPtr` is not freed causing a memory leak.

Again: No type `VOID` and `MyStructData`.

Again: Use of function (`free`) without prototype.

Now regarding your findings:

> I see the void pointer is declared, then in InitFunction, pMyStructData has
> malloc with size of the struct MyStructData.

Apart from the issues I mentioned abov, that is fine. That is how allocating memory for structs is don.

> Next the pPtr member is accessed and malloc-ed a big chunk (1024)... this
> is where I see an issue. Since the pPtr member was declared as void,
> pMyStructData is too small to allocate 1024 bytes?

That is no issue. The member `ptr` points to some memory provided by `malloc` There is no relation to the struct where the pointer itself resides. It does not need to fit into the struct.
You only should check for `NULL` before this.

Comment: All this effort and the OP changes the tag  :( +1

Comment: It was never specified to me if the problem is in C or C++... his answer is valid!
Geez.

Comment: @Farnsworth - perhaps you could describe the ENTIRE context of the problem, what you know, where it came from, who communicated it to you, when you are to finish, how you are to submit it, etc. As it stands this is a pretty inconsiderate post.

Comment: @Farnsworth How is this, you are programming but you don't know if you are on C or C++? Are you aware that they are very different languages?

Comment: @Farnsworth Actually, you *did* specify that you want an answer regarding C. That is what language tags are used for.

Comment: Friends, there is no context. I am practicing and this is the entirety of the problem as I received it. An image of the code snippet that says, "outline everything wrong with this code." I was not told if it is in C or C++. @DavidRanieri Yes, I am not stupid. I realize these are different languages. Thank you for that.

Comment: No one ever called you stupid, there are a lot of people who don't distinguish C from C++